When is $\int_T^\infty e^{-\delta t} \frac{\cos 2\pi t}{1-t^2} dt = 0$?
Let $\delta>0$ be small. What are the values $T$ for which
$$\int_T^\infty e^{-\delta t} \frac{\cos \pi t}{1/4-t^2} dt = 0\;\;\;\;\;\;?$$
I don't have a good reason for expecting a closed expression, other than dimly remembering that sometimes there are beautiful answers to this kind of question, where what underlies the answers is periods, algebraic geometry and what have you.
Context: the Fourier transform of $\cos(\pi t)|_{[-1/2,1/2]}$ is $\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{\cos \pi t}{1/4 - t^2}$.

Just to say what should be obvious - we can write the integral above equals the imaginary part of
$$e^{\delta/2} E_1((\delta-\pi i)(T+1/2)) + e^{-\delta/2} E_1((\delta-\pi i) (T-1/2))$$
for $T>1/2$. The proof consists just in writing $\frac{1}{1/4-t^2} = \frac{1}{1/2+t} + \frac{1}{1/2-t}$ and $e^{x} \cos(y) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{x + i y} + e^{x- i y})$.

Do people just hate integrals?

I'm unsure what kind of answer you would find satisfactory; for $\delta=0$ you seek the solution of $\text{Si}(\frac{\pi }{2}-\pi  T)+\pi=\text{Si}(\frac{\pi }{2}+\pi  T)$; this can only be solved numerically, don't you think so?

@CarloBeenakker How do you know it can only be solved numerically?

well, an exact solution is unlikely, but I found an accurate approximation (see answer box)

@CarloBeenaker Sure, though I don't think that's useful for what I really had in mind (namely, integrating the absolute value of the integral as $T$ varies). Let me see if something can be done for the case $\delta=0$, at least.

The large-$T$ expansion gives
$$e^{\delta T}\int_T^\infty e^{-\delta t} \frac{\cos \pi t}{1/4-t^2} dt =\frac{ \pi  \sin \pi  T-\delta \cos \pi  T}{\left(\delta^2+\pi ^2\right) T^2}+{\cal O}(T^{-3}),$$
which vanishes at
$$T_n=n+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(\delta/\pi)+{\cal O}(1/n),\;\;n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
This is accurate already for small $n\gtrsim 3$. The values of $T$ at which the integral vanishes thus vary from integers for $\delta\ll 1$ to half-integers for $\delta\gg 1$.


Here is a plot for $\delta=0.2$ of the integral as a function of $T$ (gold) and the large-$T$ approximation (blue). The two curves are very close for relatively small $T$.

The convergence can be accelerated by including the next order term,
$$T_n=n+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(\delta/\pi)+\frac{2}{\pi^2 n}+{\cal O}(1/n^2),\;\;n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Here is a plot of $T_n-n-2/\pi^2 n$ as a function of $n$, still for $\delta=0.2$, showing the rapid approach to $\pi^{-1}\arctan(\delta/\pi)=0.0202$.


